# How to scroll ScrollView of EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have following layout:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <EditText/>
        <EditText/>
        ...
        <EditText/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`EditText`s are added dynamically to the `ScrollView`.

`EditText`s should be focusable(at least `focusableInTouchMode`)

The question is - how to scroll that view with touching on one of the `EditText`s and making a scroll gesture), since now scrolling the works only if touching outside of the `EditText`s?
Is it possible at all?

**UPD** Marked the first answer as a solution(with plain solution to provide a scroll), since my question is incorrect and answer is plain right - my scrolling problem was a result of using a `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView`.

Sorry for misdirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ScrollView can only have one child, so you should make a LinearLayout in the ScrollView and then add the EditTexts to it. The scrolling should then work automatically when necessary.

Comment: I've corrected the layout. `LinearLayout` presence is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Set the

`android:marginLeft=10dp
 android:marginRight=10dp`

so that it has some space on the right and left to scroll. Of course if the whole screen is filled with `EditTexts` one of them will take focus when user tap to scroll.

Comment: So, it's impossible without the padding/margin set?

Comment: Give a try to 

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

as answered by Pragnani.

Comment: Please see the question - setting `focusableInTouchMode` is not accepted(`EditText` should be focusable by touching it)

Answer (score 0):

set this attributes to your edittext

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Please see the question - setting `focusableInTouchMode` is not acceptable(`EditText` should be focusable by touching it)

Comment: @m1shk4 Then the solution probably setting the margin for each EditText

Comment: So it's impossible without the margin/padding way?